# Cambiar background de color al hacer click

Tags: javascript, css, angular7

tengo una pequeña duda a ver si pueden hecharme una mano para resolverla, quiero cambiar el fondo de un div al hacer click, os pongo en situacion

Tengo 5 divs, **todos con el mismo nombre de clase**, al **hacer click en el div número uno quiero que cambie el color de fondo** pero **si luego hago click en el div numero dos quiero que el div numero uno vuelva a tener el background anterior** y ahora cambie el fondo del div número dos

```
<div class="visitas" (click)="enableDisableRule()" [style.background-color]="toggle ? '#8f9ba6' : '#5a6668'">
    <span>Juan López - 10:30</span>
</div>
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi componente TS

```
  toggle = true;
  status = 'Enable'; 

  enableDisableRule(job) {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    this.status = this.toggle ? 'Enable' : 'Disable';
  }
```

Comment: ¿ Pero solo cambiará de color el div1 ¿ que pasa si pulso primero en el 3, 4 ó 5  y luego hago click en el mismo ? Puedes agregar el funcionamiento completo o sólo tiene el funcionamiento el 1º div ?

Comment: Hola @EduBw al hacer click en el div 1 cambiara de color si hago click en el div 2 cambia de color el div 2 y el div 1 vuelve a su color original, si hago click en el div 3 el div 2 vuelve a su color original y el div 3 cambia de color, así sucesivamente, es como si fuese un botón pulsado...

Answer (score 2):

Una posible solución:

html

```
<div class="visitas" (click)="enableDisableRule($event.target)">
    <span>Juan López - 10:30</span>
</div>
```

ts

```
enableDisableRule(elem) {
   const colorOne = "rgb(90, 102, 104)";
   const colorTwo = "rgb(143, 155, 166)";
   if (elem.className !== "visitas"){ 
      elem = elem.closest('.visitas'); 
   }
   elem.style.backgroundColor = (elem.style.backgroundColor == colorOne) ? colorTwo : colorOne;
 }
```

- No se esta inicializando con ningún background-color por defecto, si deseas hacerlo debes agregarlo en la clase "visitas" o añadiéndolo directamente con el atributo "style" en el elemento html.
- Los colores deben estar en formato rgb para que la validación de elem.style.backgroundColor == colorOne sea correcta, ya que al asignar un color con el style.backgroundColor de javascript lo transforma automáticamente a rgb.
- El $event.target nos puede devolver el elemento en el que tenemos la funcion (click) o algun elemento hijo en caso de que se haga click en alguno de ellos, por eso el siguiente if:

  if (elem.className !== "visitas"){ 
            elem = elem.closest('.visitas'); 
         }

Aquí tienes una pequeña prueba de como funciona: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-auws9w

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución es la siguiente manteniendo tu lógica:

```
status = 'Enable';
toggle = [true, true, true, true, true];


enableDisableRule(idx) {
    if ( this.toggle[idx] ) {
      this.toggle[idx] = false;
      let cnt = 0;
      this.toggle.forEach( e => {
        if ( cnt !== idx ) {
          this.toggle[cnt] = true;
        }
        cnt++;
      });
    } else {
      this.toggle[idx] = true;
    }
    this.status = this.toggle[idx] ? 'Enable' : 'Disable';
  }
```

En el html

```
<div class="visitas" (click)="enableDisableRule(0)" [style.background-color]="toggle[0] ? '#8f9ba6' : '#5a6668'">
  <span>Juan López - 10:30</span>
</div>

<div class="visitas" (click)="enableDisableRule(1)" [style.background-color]="toggle[1] ? '#8f9ba6' : '#5a6668'">
  <span>Juan López - 10:30</span>
</div>

<div class="visitas" (click)="enableDisableRule(2)" [style.background-color]="toggle[2] ? '#8f9ba6' : '#5a6668'">
  <span>Juan López - 10:30</span>
</div>

<div class="visitas" (click)="enableDisableRule(3)" [style.background-color]="toggle[3] ? '#8f9ba6' : '#5a6668'">
  <span>Juan López - 10:30</span>
</div>

<div class="visitas" (click)="enableDisableRule(4)" [style.background-color]="toggle[4] ? '#8f9ba6' : '#5a6668'">
  <span>Juan López - 10:30</span>
</div>
```